# Comparison between DBSCAN and single linkage hierarchical clustering

Tags: clustering, dbscan

I am studying clustering algorithms and I want to find a good example where single link hierarchical clustering algorithm returns better cluster results than DBSCAN (having provided valid parameters). Is there a good dataset either real world or generated?

Comment: 'Better' is somewhat elusive in clustering. Also both algorithms you mention have free parameters. So what do you mean by 'better'?

Comment: @Valentas With "better" I mean that no matter what parameters we choose for DBSCAN , single link provides a better clustering. From theory we know that single link is susceptible to noise but works perfectly with well defined clusters and DBSCAN can work perfectly with noise but has an issue when data density varies. So my question is in which dataset could single link return a good clustering and DBSCAN not (with of course having picked valid parameters and not trying to make the algorithm return the results we want).